# static IP and using wireless connection to internet

Tags: static-ip

I intend to setup static IP for my raspberry using jessie ver 8. I intend have a static IP to remote my computer to Rpi using VNC through a Ethernet cable so I can see my Rpi screen for this simple purpose, and the other plan is another static IP to connect wirelessly over a network which has a internet access(in short I like the Rpi has internet access). I understand this question had asked few times so I tried to gathered the past info and follow, but still I couldn't get the wireless connection to connect properly which mean it having trouble connecting to internet but it has no problem connect to local network when I tried to ping a local computer in the same network.

/etc/dhcpcd.conf

```
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
#duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Most distributions have NTP support.
option ntp_servers
# Respect the network MTU.
# Some interface drivers reset when changing the MTU so disabled by default.
#option interface_mtu

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses instead of hardware based ones
slaac private

# A hook script is provided to lookup the hostname if not set by the DHCP
# server, but it should not be run by default.
nohook lookup-hostname

interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.11.100/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1

interface wlan0
static ip_address=172.20.11.100/24
static routers=172.20.0.1
static domain_name_servers=172.20.0.1
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Is there something wrong written that why it isn't connecting to internet? Appreciate your help and thank you!

Comment: You have not provided any information.

Comment: I put some more details. Hope it explained more.

Comment: `172.20.11.100/24` is not an internal IP in your network.

Comment: In addition to the comment from @hcheung: for `wlan0` it should be something like `172.20.0.100/24`, or the routers should be e.g. `172.20.11.1`. Same for `eth0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out but it work. I should leave the static routers and 
static domain_name_servers parameter blank, it automatically configure it.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.